# offset a second series in chart control where x axis is a string

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, .net-4.0

How do you offset a second series in chart control where x axis is a string in MS chart control.

I would like to keep the x Axis as a string.

In the below example of my problem I would like serise Test2 to start at x axis position "test 4", however currently they both start at "test 1" even though the first x axis point is at "test 4" for series Test2 ?

I guess I'm looking for an offset where I can say series Test2 start at x axis point 4 or an index to axis where I can add the point explicitly, but I can't see how to do either.

Also, but less of an issue, how do I start the Series TEST1 at the Y axis?

here is a simple example of my dilemma:

```
Series test1 = new Series("Test1");
Series test2 = new Series("Test2");
int x =1;
test1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    test1.Points.AddXY("test" + x.ToString(), i);
    x++;
}

chart1.Series.Add(test1);
x = 4; // I would like to start plotting this series at "test 4"

for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
{

    test2.Points.AddXY("test" + x.ToString(), i);
    x++;
}

chart1.Series.Add(test2);

foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
{
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    series.BorderWidth = 5;

}
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
```

Currently this displays as below:
[image: current output]

Comment: Please see my update!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to properly work with the data in a Series once you have decided to add the x-values as strings. That is because they are lost when the string are converted to double, resulting to all x-values being  `0d`.

So you can't refer to their values. Instead you can simply insert the necessary number of **empty** `DataPoints`. So if you want to offset the series by three data points you can write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   DataPoint dp0 = new DataPoint() 
                  {XValue = 0, IsEmpty = true, Color = Color.Transparent };
   test2.Points.Insert(0, dp0);
}
```

[image]

Note that you may want to control how `Empty DataPoints` are displayed in a `Series` be setting  in the [`Series.EmptyPointStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.emptypointstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also note that I have cleared the default `series1`: `chart1.Series.Clear();` before adding the new ones.

**Update:** I have only just now noticed your second question.

The problem here is that the usual solution, which is quite simple ans straight-forward, will not work. Here is is:

```
  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
```

This would work, if only your values were numbers. But as you added them as string none of the various things, like: Interval, IntervalOffset, Minimum, Maximum or zomme and range settings will work.

So The real and correct solution is to add the data as you should. Here is an example:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {

        int px = test1.Points.AddXY(x, i);
        test1.Points[px].AxisLabel = "test" + x;
        x++;
    }
```

This creates the output you want and still keeps the DataPoints' x-values:

[image]